# Issue with matching pattern with wildcard characters

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm writing a lotusscript agent which will run once in every 5 minutes and will send an email alert if the SEMDEBUG.TXT log file on the server exceeds a certain threshold. The code which accesses this file is mentioned below.

```
strSemDebugFilePath$ = "D:\IBM\Domino\Data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\SEMDEBUG_<server_name>_" & CStr(Year(Now())) & "_" & strMonth &"_" & strDay & "@" & strHour & "_" & strMin & "_*.TXT"

strSemDebugFileName$ = Dir$(strSemDebugFilePath$,0)
```

As this agent runs once in every 5 minutes, I have set the value of variable strMin such that it decrements 5 minutes from the current time so that when the agent runs, it will check if the log file size has exceeded the threshold in the past 5 minutes. The line of code for this is mentioned below.

```
strMin = CStr(Minute(Now()))
    If Int(strMin) > 5 Then
        strMin = CStr(Int(strMin)-5)
    End If
    If Len(strMin)=1 Then
        strMin="0"&strMin
    End If
```

Now the problem is that I'm using the pattern matching [0-strMin] in place of the variable strMin in the line of code which will access the SEMDEBUG.TXT file and this is not working for some reason. So the final line of code is mentioned below.

```
strSemDebugFilePath$ = "D:\IBM\Domino\Data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\SEMDEBUG_<server_name>_" & CStr(Year(Now())) & "_" & strMonth &"_" & strDay & "@" & strHour & "_" & "[00-strMin]" & "_*.TXT"
```

The pattern matching [00-strMin] in the above line is not working. It is not returning the proper result. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

P.S.: I have also tried the below pattern matchings just to verify whether matching in character list works or not. But none of them are working apart from the wildcard character *.
[0-9], [0-90-9], [#]
None of the above are working.
Only * is working, which I have also used in the code before matching for the ".TXT" part, and it is working absolutely fine.

Comment: shouldn't it be `strSemDebugFilePath$ = "D:\IBM\Domino\Data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\SEMDEBUG_<server_name>_" & CStr(Year(Now())) & "_" & strMonth &"_" & strDay & "@" & strHour & "_" & "[00-" & strMin & "]" & "_*.TXT"`

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for the  Dir$  function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fr/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_DIR_FUNCTION.html) says

> Standard wildcard characters can be used in fileSpec to designate all
>   files satisfying the wildcard criterion. Asterisk ( * ) for either the
>   file name or the extension designates all files with any characters in
>   that position. Question mark ( ? ) in any character position in either
>   part of the name designates any single character in that position.

It says nothing about "#" or ranges like "[00-99]", leading me to conclude that that sort of pattern matching is not supported.

It seems to me that you're probably going to have to use a combination of the Dir$ with "*" or "??" and the [like operator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fr/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_LIKE_OPERATOR.html) in order to do what you want.

Comment: Richard is right, the Dir function relies on the OS which provides only primative pattern matching.  One alternative would be to use the DIR to return a set of possible matches (SEMDEBUG_* for example) and then iterate what it returns and use pattern matching on each until you find what you're looking for.  (I've used a java class called from LS for RegEx in the past.)  Of course if you're doing that, you might as well just build the string and do a plain old string comparison.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that is right. Pattern matching isn't supported within Dir$ function. I have modified the code as suggested by Duston. I'm using 'Like' operator to match the pattern in the iteration. Pattern matching works here but unfortunately I'm not able to use variables inside the pattern. It is working for hardcoded digits like [0-9]. But specifying variables like "'['&strMinDiff&'-'&strMin&']'" isn't working. Tried different ways but no luck.

Comment: The modified code is pasted below: `If strSemDebugFiles(var) Like "SEMDEBUG_VMPWAO2_" & CStr(Year(Now())) & "_" & strMonth &"_" & strDay & "@" & strHour & "_" & "'['&strMinDiff&'-'&strMin&']'" & "_*.TXT" Then
   <Sending Email logic goes here!!!!!>
   End If`